# Unable to install informatica in windows 8

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm unable to instal informatica in windows 8.can any one please advice. attached the error log

error log:

Tuesday, July 29, 2014

This log was generated during Informatica 9.1.0 with HotFix 2 Services installation

Components installing are ... : server,ODBC6.1,isp,services,java,tomcat,tools,DataTransformation,jasperreports-server-4.0.1-bin

Disk Space Check Enabled  : true

Enter the installation directory : F:\Informatica_install

Required Disk Space: 1,712 MB

Available Disk Space: 107,112 MB

Registry Entry

---

Registry Key : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Informatica 9.1.0
Value Name : ROOT_DIR
Data   : F:\Informatica_install

Registry Key : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Informatica 9.1.0\Server
Value Name : ISP_HOME
Data   : F:\Informatica_install\isp

Installing VS C++ 2008 RT

---

F:\Informatica_install\tools\VS2008\vcredist_x64.exe /q

COMMAND_EXITCODE: 1

## Configuring files

F:\Informatica_install\services\MetadataManagerService\utilities\mmcmd\mmcmd.bat
F:\Informatica_install\services\MetadataManagerService\utilities\mmBackupUtil\backupCmdLine.bat

---

Creating Shortcuts

Installing VS C++ 2005 RT

---

cd /d "F:\Informatica_install\DataTransformation\bin"
vcredist_x64.exe /q:a /c:"VCREDI~2.EXE /q:a /c:""msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qn /l*v %SystemDrive%\vcredist.log"" "

COMMAND_EXITCODE: 0

Test Connection Exception -java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [informatica][Oracle JDBC Driver]Error establishing socket to host and port: localhost:1521. Reason: Connection refused: connect

Test Connection Exception -java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [informatica][Oracle JDBC Driver]Error establishing socket to host and port: localhost:1521. Reason: Connection refused: connect

DB TYPE : Oracle

Database user ID: : system

User password: : *****

Custom JDBC Connection String : jdbc:informatica:oracle://localhost:1521;ServiceName=orcl;MaxPooledStatements=20;CatalogOptions=0;BatchPerformanceWorkaround=true

Domain name: : Domain_Sai

Node host name: : Sai

Node name: : node01_Sai

Node port number: : 6005

NODE_ADDRESS : Sai:6005

LOGS_DIRECTORY : F:\Informatica_install\isp\logs

BACKUP_DIRECTORY : F:\Informatica_install\server\infa_shared\Backup

DOMAIN_USER : Administrator

DOMAIN_PSSWD : *****

NODEOPTIONS_XML : F:\Informatica_install\isp\bin\nodeoptions.xml

Free ports detected by the installer:

Service Manager port:6006

Informatica Administrator port:6007

Service Manager shutdown port:6008

Informatica Administrator shutdown port:6009

Command Executed : F:\Informatica_install\isp\bin\infasetup.bat  defineDomain -du "system" -dp  -dt "Oracle" -dn "Domain_Sai" -cs "jdbc:informatica:oracle://localhost:1521;ServiceName=orcl;MaxPooledStatements=20;CatalogOptions=0;BatchPerformanceWorkaround=true" -nn "node01_Sai" -na "Sai:6005" -ad "Administrator" -pd  -rf "F:\Informatica_install\isp\bin\nodeoptions.xml" -sp "6006" -ap "6008" -mi "6013" -ma "6113" -sv "6007" -asp "6009" -f -ld "F:\Informatica_install\isp\logs" -bd "F:\Informatica_install\server\infa_shared\Backup" -tls "false"

Exit Code : 1

OutPut :

Error : '"F:\Informatica_install\java\jre\bin\java"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Domain name: : Domain_Admin

Node host name: : Sai

Node name: : node01_Sai

Node port number: : 6005

NODE_ADDRESS : Sai:6005

LOGS_DIRECTORY : F:\Informatica_install\isp\logs

BACKUP_DIRECTORY : F:\Informatica_install\server\infa_shared\Backup

DOMAIN_USER : Administrator

DOMAIN_PSSWD : *****

NODEOPTIONS_XML : F:\Informatica_install\isp\bin\nodeoptions.xml

Free ports detected by the installer:

Service Manager port:6006

Informatica Administrator port:6007

Service Manager shutdown port:6008

Informatica Administrator shutdown port:6009

Command Executed : F:\Informatica_install\isp\bin\infasetup.bat  defineDomain -du "system" -dp  -dt "Oracle" -dn "Domain_Admin" -cs "jdbc:informatica:oracle://localhost:1521;ServiceName=orcl;MaxPooledStatements=20;CatalogOptions=0;BatchPerformanceWorkaround=true" -nn "node01_Sai" -na "Sai:6005" -ad "Administrator" -pd  -rf "F:\Informatica_install\isp\bin\nodeoptions.xml" -sp "6006" -ap "6008" -mi "6013" -ma "6113" -sv "6007" -asp "6009" -f -ld "F:\Informatica_install\isp\logs" -bd "F:\Informatica_install\server\infa_shared\Backup" -tls "false"

Exit Code : 1

OutPut :

Error : '"F:\Informatica_install\java\jre\bin\java"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

DB TYPE : Oracle

Database user ID: : system

User password: : *****

Custom JDBC Connection String : jdbc:informatica:oracle://localhost:1521;ServiceName=orcl;MaxPooledStatements=20;CatalogOptions=0;BatchPerformanceWorkaround=true

Domain name: : Domain_Sai

Node host name: : Sai

Node name: : node01_Sai

Node port number: : 6005

NODE_ADDRESS : Sai:6005

LOGS_DIRECTORY : F:\Informatica_install\isp\logs

BACKUP_DIRECTORY : F:\Informatica_install\server\infa_shared\Backup

DOMAIN_USER : Administrator

DOMAIN_PSSWD : *****

NODEOPTIONS_XML : F:\Informatica_install\isp\bin\nodeoptions.xml

Free ports detected by the installer:

Service Manager port:6006

Informatica Administrator port:6007

Service Manager shutdown port:6008

Informatica Administrator shutdown port:6009

Command Executed : F:\Informatica_install\isp\bin\infasetup.bat  defineDomain -du "system" -dp  -dt "Oracle" -dn "Domain_Sai" -cs "jdbc:informatica:oracle://localhost:1521;ServiceName=orcl;MaxPooledStatements=20;CatalogOptions=0;BatchPerformanceWorkaround=true" -nn "node01_Sai" -na "Sai:6005" -ad "Administrator" -pd  -rf "F:\Informatica_install\isp\bin\nodeoptions.xml" -sp "6006" -ap "6008" -mi "6013" -ma "6113" -sv "6007" -asp "6009" -f -ld "F:\Informatica_install\isp\logs" -bd "F:\Informatica_install\server\infa_shared\Backup" -tls "false"

Exit Code : -1

OutPut : [ICMD_10033] Command [defineDomain] failed with error [[INFASETUP_10002] Cannot create the domain because of the following error: [RSVCSHARED_00014] Internal error. The Repository Capability ['Persistence'] failed to initialize for the following reason: '[PERSISTENCEAPI_0307] [DBPERSISTER_0014] Internal error. A test query execution caused an exception. Contact Informatica Global Customer Support. This was caused by [PERSISTENCEAPI_0307] [VIEWS_0014] Failed to create view 'MRI_MRSSCHEMATES51593' This was caused by [informatica][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
'. Contact Informatica Global Customer Support..].

Error : Jul 29, 2014 3:18:06 PM com.informatica.isp.domainrepositoryservice.impl.PRSDomainRepositoryServiceImpl initDB
INFO: Domain Repository Service init method is called.
Jul 29, 2014 3:18:09 PM com.informatica.repository.persistence.service.impl.PersistenceManagerImpl initialize
SEVERE: Unable to initialize persistence component due to: [PERSISTENCEAPI_0307] [DBPERSISTER_0014] Internal error. A test query execution caused an exception. Contact Informatica Global Customer Support. This was caused by [PERSISTENCEAPI_0307] [VIEWS_0014] Failed to create view 'MRI_MRSSCHEMATES51593' This was caused by [informatica][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

com.informatica.repository.persistence.PersistenceInternalException: [PERSISTENCEAPI_0307] [DBPERSISTER_0014] Internal error. A test query execution caused an exception. Contact Informatica Global Customer Support. This was caused by [PERSISTENCEAPI_0307] [VIEWS_0014] Failed to create view 'MRI_MRSSCHEMATES51593' This was caused by [informatica][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

```
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.database.DatabaseHandler.detectSchemaName(DatabaseHandler.java:1098)
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.database.DatabaseHandler.getSchemaName(DatabaseHandler.java:838)
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.database.DDLGenRepositoryConfigurationManagerImpl.initializeConfiguration(DDLGenRepositoryConfigurationManager.java:310)
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.database.DDLGenRepositoryConfigurationManagerImpl.<init>(DDLGenRepositoryConfigurationManager.java:287)
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.database.DatabaseRepositoryHandler.<init>(DatabaseRepositoryHandler.java:122)
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.database.DatabasePersister.createRepositoryHandler(DatabasePersister.java:51)
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.service.impl.AbstractPersister.initialize(AbstractPersister.java:100)
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.service.impl.PersistenceManagerImpl.initialize(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:96)
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.service.impl.PersistenceManagerImpl.initialize(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:67)
at com.informatica.repository.service.capability.impl.persistence.PersistenceCapabilityManagerImpl.init(PersistenceCapabilityManagerImpl.java:125)
at com.informatica.repository.service.impl.RepositoryServiceManagerImpl.initPersistence(RepositoryServiceManagerImpl.java:1025)
at com.informatica.repository.service.impl.RepositoryServiceManagerImpl.initService(RepositoryServiceManagerImpl.java:236)
at com.informatica.repository.deployer.embedded.EmbeddedRepositoryConnectionFactory.initializeRepositorySvc(EmbeddedRepositoryConnectionFactory.java:513)
at com.informatica.repository.deployer.embedded.EmbeddedRepositoryConnectionFactory.connect(EmbeddedRepositoryConnectionFactory.java:182)
at com.informatica.project.repository.deployer.common.SetupEmbeddedJRS.getEmbeddedJRSInstance(SetupEmbeddedJRS.java:94)
at com.informatica.project.repository.deployer.embedded.EmbeddedConnectionFactory.initializeProjectRepoSvc(EmbeddedConnectionFactory.java:458)
at com.informatica.project.repository.deployer.embedded.EmbeddedConnectionFactory.connect(EmbeddedConnectionFactory.java:162)
at com.informatica.isp.domainrepositoryservice.impl.PRSDomainRepositoryServiceImpl.initImpl(PRSDomainRepositoryServiceImpl.java:226)
at com.informatica.isp.domainrepositoryservice.impl.PRSDomainRepositoryServiceImpl.initDB(PRSDomainRepositoryServiceImpl.java:639)
at com.informatica.isp.domainrepositoryservice.impl.PRSDomainRepositoryServiceImpl.init(PRSDomainRepositoryServiceImpl.java:536)
at com.informatica.isp.infasetup.impl.ConfigDomainPluginImpl.defineDomain(ConfigDomainPluginImpl.java:225)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.pcsf.cmdframework.PluginCommand.run(PluginCommand.java:46)
at com.informatica.pcsf.cmdframework.Infasetup.execute(Infasetup.java:190)
at com.informatica.pcsf.cmdframework.Infasetup.main(Infasetup.java:85)
```

Caused by: com.informatica.repository.persistence.PersistenceInitializationException: [PERSISTENCEAPI_0307] [VIEWS_0014] Failed to create view 'MRI_MRSSCHEMATES51593' This was caused by [informatica][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

```
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.database.oracle.OracleHandler.createView(OracleHandler.java:599)
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.database.DatabaseHandler.detectSchemaName(DatabaseHandler.java:1084)
... 27 more
```

Caused by: com.informatica.repository.persistence.ExceptionSurrogate: java.sql.SQLException: [informatica][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

```
at com.informatica.jdbc.oraclebase.ddb9.b(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.jdbc.oraclebase.ddb9.a(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.jdbc.oraclebase.ddb8.b(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.jdbc.oraclebase.ddb8.a(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.jdbc.oracle.ddm.q(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.jdbc.oraclebase.ddel.v(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.jdbc.oraclebase.ddel.x(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.jdbc.oraclebase.ddel.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.database.oracle.OracleHandler.createView(OracleHandler.java:597)
... 28 more
```

Test Connection Exception -java.sql.SQLException: [informatica][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01045: user SAI lacks CREATE SESSION privilege; logon denied

Test Connection Exception -java.sql.SQLException: [informatica][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01045: user SAI lacks CREATE SESSION privilege; logon denied

Test Connection Exception -java.sql.SQLException: [informatica][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01045: user SAI lacks CREATE SESSION privilege; logon denied

Test Connection Exception -java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: [informatica][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

DB TYPE : Oracle

Database user ID: : system

User password: : *****

Custom JDBC Connection String : jdbc:informatica:oracle://localhost:1521;ServiceName=orcl;MaxPooledStatements=20;CatalogOptions=0;BatchPerformanceWorkaround=true

Domain name: : Domain_Sai

Node host name: : Sai

Node name: : node01_Sai

Node port number: : 6005

NODE_ADDRESS : Sai:6005

LOGS_DIRECTORY : F:\Informatica_install\isp\logs

BACKUP_DIRECTORY : F:\Informatica_install\server\infa_shared\Backup

DOMAIN_USER : Administrator

DOMAIN_PSSWD : *****

NODEOPTIONS_XML : F:\Informatica_install\isp\bin\nodeoptions.xml

Free ports detected by the installer:

Service Manager port:6006

Informatica Administrator port:6007

Service Manager shutdown port:6008

Informatica Administrator shutdown port:6009

Command Executed : F:\Informatica_install\isp\bin\infasetup.bat  defineDomain -du "system" -dp  -dt "Oracle" -dn "Domain_Sai" -cs "jdbc:informatica:oracle://localhost:1521;ServiceName=orcl;MaxPooledStatements=20;CatalogOptions=0;BatchPerformanceWorkaround=true" -nn "node01_Sai" -na "Sai:6005" -ad "Administrator" -pd  -rf "F:\Informatica_install\isp\bin\nodeoptions.xml" -sp "6006" -ap "6008" -mi "6013" -ma "6113" -sv "6007" -asp "6009" -f -ld "F:\Informatica_install\isp\logs" -bd "F:\Informatica_install\server\infa_shared\Backup" -tls "false"

Exit Code : -1

OutPut : [ICMD_10033] Command [defineDomain] failed with error [[INFASETUP_10002] Cannot create the domain because of the following error: [RSVCSHARED_00014] Internal error. The Repository Capability ['Persistence'] failed to initialize for the following reason: '[PERSISTENCEAPI_0307] [DBPERSISTER_0014] Internal error. A test query execution caused an exception. Contact Informatica Global Customer Support. This was caused by [PERSISTENCEAPI_0307] [VIEWS_0014] Failed to create view 'MRI_MRSSCHEMATES33840' This was caused by [informatica][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
'. Contact Informatica Global Customer Support..].

Error : Jul 29, 2014 3:20:18 PM com.informatica.isp.domainrepositoryservice.impl.PRSDomainRepositoryServiceImpl initDB
INFO: Domain Repository Service init method is called.
Jul 29, 2014 3:20:19 PM com.informatica.repository.persistence.service.impl.PersistenceManagerImpl initialize
SEVERE: Unable to initialize persistence component due to: [PERSISTENCEAPI_0307] [DBPERSISTER_0014] Internal error. A test query execution caused an exception. Contact Informatica Global Customer Support. This was caused by [PERSISTENCEAPI_0307] [VIEWS_0014] Failed to create view 'MRI_MRSSCHEMATES33840' This was caused by [informatica][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

com.informatica.repository.persistence.PersistenceInternalException: [PERSISTENCEAPI_0307] [DBPERSISTER_0014] Internal error. A test query execution caused an exception. Contact Informatica Global Customer Support. This was caused by [PERSISTENCEAPI_0307] [VIEWS_0014] Failed to create view 'MRI_MRSSCHEMATES33840' This was caused by [informatica][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

```
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.database.DatabaseHandler.detectSchemaName(DatabaseHandler.java:1098)
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.database.DatabaseHandler.getSchemaName(DatabaseHandler.java:838)
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.database.DDLGenRepositoryConfigurationManagerImpl.initializeConfiguration(DDLGenRepositoryConfigurationManager.java:310)
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.database.DDLGenRepositoryConfigurationManagerImpl.<init>(DDLGenRepositoryConfigurationManager.java:287)
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.database.DatabaseRepositoryHandler.<init>(DatabaseRepositoryHandler.java:122)
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.database.DatabasePersister.createRepositoryHandler(DatabasePersister.java:51)
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.service.impl.AbstractPersister.initialize(AbstractPersister.java:100)
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.service.impl.PersistenceManagerImpl.initialize(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:96)
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.service.impl.PersistenceManagerImpl.initialize(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:67)
at com.informatica.repository.service.capability.impl.persistence.PersistenceCapabilityManagerImpl.init(PersistenceCapabilityManagerImpl.java:125)
at com.informatica.repository.service.impl.RepositoryServiceManagerImpl.initPersistence(RepositoryServiceManagerImpl.java:1025)
at com.informatica.repository.service.impl.RepositoryServiceManagerImpl.initService(RepositoryServiceManagerImpl.java:236)
at com.informatica.repository.deployer.embedded.EmbeddedRepositoryConnectionFactory.initializeRepositorySvc(EmbeddedRepositoryConnectionFactory.java:513)
at com.informatica.repository.deployer.embedded.EmbeddedRepositoryConnectionFactory.connect(EmbeddedRepositoryConnectionFactory.java:182)
at com.informatica.project.repository.deployer.common.SetupEmbeddedJRS.getEmbeddedJRSInstance(SetupEmbeddedJRS.java:94)
at com.informatica.project.repository.deployer.embedded.EmbeddedConnectionFactory.initializeProjectRepoSvc(EmbeddedConnectionFactory.java:458)
at com.informatica.project.repository.deployer.embedded.EmbeddedConnectionFactory.connect(EmbeddedConnectionFactory.java:162)
at com.informatica.isp.domainrepositoryservice.impl.PRSDomainRepositoryServiceImpl.initImpl(PRSDomainRepositoryServiceImpl.java:226)
at com.informatica.isp.domainrepositoryservice.impl.PRSDomainRepositoryServiceImpl.initDB(PRSDomainRepositoryServiceImpl.java:639)
at com.informatica.isp.domainrepositoryservice.impl.PRSDomainRepositoryServiceImpl.init(PRSDomainRepositoryServiceImpl.java:536)
at com.informatica.isp.infasetup.impl.ConfigDomainPluginImpl.defineDomain(ConfigDomainPluginImpl.java:225)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.pcsf.cmdframework.PluginCommand.run(PluginCommand.java:46)
at com.informatica.pcsf.cmdframework.Infasetup.execute(Infasetup.java:190)
at com.informatica.pcsf.cmdframework.Infasetup.main(Infasetup.java:85)
```

Caused by: com.informatica.repository.persistence.PersistenceInitializationException: [PERSISTENCEAPI_0307] [VIEWS_0014] Failed to create view 'MRI_MRSSCHEMATES33840' This was caused by [informatica][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

```
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.database.oracle.OracleHandler.createView(OracleHandler.java:599)
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.database.DatabaseHandler.detectSchemaName(DatabaseHandler.java:1084)
... 27 more
```

Caused by: com.informatica.repository.persistence.ExceptionSurrogate: java.sql.SQLException: [informatica][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

```
at com.informatica.jdbc.oraclebase.ddb9.b(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.jdbc.oraclebase.ddb9.a(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.jdbc.oraclebase.ddb8.b(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.jdbc.oraclebase.ddb8.a(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.jdbc.oracle.ddm.q(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.jdbc.oraclebase.ddel.v(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.jdbc.oraclebase.ddel.x(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.jdbc.oraclebase.ddel.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.repository.persistence.database.oracle.OracleHandler.createView(OracleHandler.java:597)
... 28 more
```

Installation Status:ERROR

The Informatica 9.1.0 HotFix 2 installation is complete.

Tuesday, July 29, 2014

Answer (score 1):

All the errors occurred when the setup process tried to access a local instance of Oracle. You don't mention any RDBMS in your question, so my guess is that you don't have any installed.

Answer (score 0):

Successfully installed informatica 9 on windows 8. Problem is with domain creation. Rebooted my system and installed both oracle and informatica with out changing default paths. One more thing is java should be intalled in your system

Comment: I see the error was related to permissions for the user in the repo database "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges" from the log. How did you arrive at the conclusion that it was a problem with domain creation?

Answer (score -1):

When I was trying to install Informatica on Windows 8, it installed successfully, the domain was created without problems (on a remote Oracle Instance at a separate server) but when the machine was rebooted and the Informatica service was successfully started, Administration console was not available. Nothing was listening on the 6008 port.
The Informatica support told me that this Operating system is not supported and it should not work.